# How should a mac user whose default compiler is clang deal with #include <experimental/filesystem>

Tags: c++, git, macos, clang, c++17

I'm installing a project from git which is split up a bit on my **MacOS Sierra**.

I'm downloading an A branch from git which during `sudo make install` attempts to fully install an intermediate B branch for the project to function properly. Trouble is this B branch has a

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
```

called while its intermediate (automated by the `sudo make install` for project A) installation gets run within one of the files. Thus producing:

```
src/ccc.cpp:10:10: fatal error: 'experimental/filesystem' file not found
#include <experimental/filesystem>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

it does **not** help that this file which attempts to include this `<experimental/filesystem>` is in fact handled as a temporary file, so I can't go and install it manually as far as I can tell.

Naturally the solution would be to attempt updating clang (to 9.0 might I add) but that proved to no avail. So here I am asking for what I could possibly do. Thanks for any help in advance.

I have gcc installed, if it will be of any help is there any way I could maybe get `sudo make install` to use that instead?

Comment: You could edit the source and use `<boost/filesystem.hpp>` instead (also link with `boost_filesystem` and `boost_system`).  Other than this or updating your compiler there is no “magic” solution.

Comment: That would be a no no, because in case it wasn't clear enough I can't edit the source because it gets stored as a temp file during installation and it will re download the file on every re-installation. But thanks for the suggestion anyway :)

Comment: @HenriMenke That's maybe a bad idea. Think about the namespacing.

Comment: @user0042 You're right, it's not as easy as simply swapping the headers.  So basically we're down to updating the toolchain.

Comment: @madprogramer Did you run `configure` and specified the correct compiler flags before running `make install`?

Comment: @ user0042 about to go offline for the night so I'll try and make this as clear as possible:

I used the defaults (no configure arguments were specified and thus no compiler flags) as the guy who set up the project tested it on a Windows and I think also on an Ubuntu and on those it worked just fine.

I read online how enabling c++17 might work, whether by clang or gcc if you could give me the necessary flags to get it running I'd consider that a full fledged answer :>

Comment: @madprogramer _" I read online how enabling c++17 might work"_ the usual way is to set a compiler flag with `CXXFLAGS`: `-std=c++17` or `-std=c++1z`